# An Electromagnetism Paradox

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation, thermal-radiation, maxwell-equations, superconductivity

I was just pondering upon different scenarios involving superconductors , radiation and Maxwell's laws that I came up with this paradoxical problem. Consider a material which exhibits superconductivity at 5 K temperature. A loop  of wire drawn out of this material is made. This loop is sheathed by an electrical insulator containing charge q which has infinite thermal conductivity( its diathermic!). This system is put inside a box with adiabatic and perfectly reflecting  walls and which has a cooling system so that the temperature of the loop and sheath can be maintained at 5 K . The box's cooling system is turned on, on Earth, in a region containing uniform magnetic field B perpendicular to the plane of the loop. Then the system is transported to space and the box is removed so that Sun' radiation can now reach the loop and sheath. Now, because the magnetic field is absent now, initially a current will in the loop so that the magnetic field of magnitude B is maintained by the virtue of the fact that the magnetic flux through a superconducting loop cannot be changed, but slowly over time the curremt degrades due ro rise in temperature and thus resistance, this causes an electric field to be generated due to time varying magnetic field by virtue of maxwells laws, this field exerts torque on the charged sheath and hence an angular momentum is generated, doesnt this violate principle of conservation of angular momentum?

Comment: Have you considered the angular momentum of the EM field?

Comment: Hearing this for the first time can you elanorate @Superfast Jellyfish